# django 1.7.4 - makemigrations working from inside eclipse editor but not from terminal

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

Operating System - ElementaryOS Luna
Editor - Eclipse (Luna)
Plugin: Pydev / Django (1.7.4)

In Eclipse editor when I right click on project and then go to Django and then to its sub-menu, I don't see makemigrations and migrate option. But I can run these commands by choosing "custom commands for manange.py" sub-menu

But on terminal if I try to run makemigrations or migrate as an argument to manage.py, it just doesn't run. And also if I tab after manage.py, it doesn't even show in its list of commands.

So two questions

Why in Eclipse, it is not showing makemigrations/migrate, when it is able to run it in custom command??

Why on terminal is the same argument not running??

Comment: Are you using some sort of virtualenv?

Comment: Also, what's the output on the terminal for "python manage.py" ?

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction brunofitas

I observed one very interesting thing.

If I used python3.4 manage.py, I was getting list of commands showing makemigrations and migrate also

Whereas when I used just python ( which is point to python2.7) manage.py, it showed a list, where makemigrations and migrate were missing.

Inside Eclipse, the interpreter is Python 3.4 and on terminal I was using python, which is python 2.7 and that is why it was failing because manage.py doesn't give migrate and makemigrations for python 2.7

Terminal issue resolved

Comment: But then why in Eclipse, where the interpreter is 3.4, the submenu is not showing makemigrations and migrate as an option ?